# How string literals are created?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to understand the string constant pool, how string literal objects are managed in constant pool, i am not able to understand why I am getting `false` from below code where  `s2 == s4`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "abc";
    String s2 = "abcd";
    String s3 = "abc" +"d";
    String s4 = s1 + "d";
    System.out.println(s2 == s3); //  OP:  true
    System.out.println(s2 == s4); // OP:  false
 }
```

Comment: `"abc" +"d"` is a compile-time constant expression while `s1 + "d"` is not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The expression `"abc" + "d"` is a constant expression, so the concatenation is performed at *compile-time*, leading to code equivalent to:

```
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "abcd";
String s3 = "abcd";
String s4 = s1 + "d";
```

The expression `s1 + "d"` is *not* a constant expression, and is therefore performed at *execution* time, creating a new string object. Therefore although `s2` and `s3` refer to the same string object (due to constant string interning), `s2` and `s4` refer to different (but equal) string objects.

See [section 15.28 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) for more details about constant expressions.

Comment: Jon - I've fixed what I think was an oversight in your closing remarks.  It would be good to check that this is what you really meant.

Comment: Also note that if you make `s1` final, the second comparison will output `true` as well, because it will be known at compile-time that it can be considered constant.

Comment: @Slanec: Good point. I've never used a local variable as a constant before, but it does indeed work.

Comment: The real question is _why_. A simple static analysis could show that the local variable doesn't change anywhere and the value is therefore known at compile time. You can't change the `s1` value from another thread (because it's a local variable). In the linked JLS article (and a few others I tried to click through to), there isn't stated whether the compiler can decide to make this constant or not. Is it undefined, or is it a well thought design desicion to make it like this and perform no static analysis? If I made a compiler that would output `true` in OP's case, would it be illegal?

Comment: @Slanec: It's not considered a constant expression by the language. Bear in mind cases such as debugging - you could change `s1` that way, and it would be odd for that then not to be reflected by the later assignment to `s4`. I think for cases like this, simplicity and predictability is usually better than aggressive optimization. While string concatenation is *somewhat* implementation-specific, I think it would at least violate the *spirit* of the JLS for the output to be `true` in the OP's case.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, right. Debugging is a good example where this would be helpful. Thank you, everything is a little bit more clear now. No spirits have been violated in asking and answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

`s2` is created at compile-time. Memory is reserved for it and populated accordingly.

`s1 + "d"` is evaluated at runtime. Because you are using two different strings (ie. `s1` is a variable which could in theory be anything) the compiler cannot know in advance that you do not intend to change the value of the object reference.

Hence, it must allocate the memory dynamically.